# angular не работает в HTML из сервера PHP

Tags: php, html, yii2, angularjs

Я начинающий web-программист, не судите строго с:

Не работает angular в HTML из сервера PHP,код HTML приходит с сервера, а angular не читает свои директивы в этом куске кода к примеру:
   вот на сервере я отдаю HTML с angular выражением

```
echo "<h2>{{1+2}}</h2>";
```

вот frontend

```
app.controller('btnCtrl',function($scope,$http,$sce){

       $scope.sce = $sce;
       $scope.showBlock = function(e){ 


          $http({url:"/product/form",method:"post"}).then(
             function success(res){

               //в dataHtml хранится <h2>{{1+2}}</h2> строка из PhP
               $scope.dataHtml = res.data;
               console.log(res);
             },
            function error(res){
              console.log(res);
            });  
     }
});
```

вот index.html

```
        <div ng-controller="btnCtrl">
              <div ng-bind-html="sce.trustAsHtml(dataHtml)"></div>  
        </div>
```

выводится у меня что-то типа **{{1+2}}**
а хочется что бы **3**

думал может есть какая нибудь функция в angular на такой случай. Функция которая говорит: angular!!! смотри у тебя появились еще выражения прочти их! и он такой Ок бро и выводит **3** вместо **{{1+2}}** ))))

angularjs/1.7.2
всё на фрэймврке Yii2 .

надеюсь вопрос понятный )

Comment: А если сразу в коде прописать {{1+2}}, отрабатывает как положено? Почему бы не сделать вычисления на сервере? Возможно angular видит это как обычную строку, потому что она приходит после инициализации.

Comment: Здесь всё не так вообще, надо ещё раз поизучать примеры и документацию Angular.  Без обид. Иначе потратите время впустую.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @diproart.@Grayd2 вам следует еще по изучать ангуляр, что бы понять его концепцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам для этого надо сообщить анугляру, что пришел текст с выражением и его надо обрабатывать. Для этого существует [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) сервис.

Пример.

```js
angular
  .module("myModule", [])
  .controller("myController", ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.txt = "<b>result = {{1+2}}</b>";
    $scope.submit = function() {
      var html = $compile($scope.txt)($scope);
      var $elem =  angular.element(display);
      $elem.empty();
      $elem.append(html);
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <textarea ng-model="txt"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="submit()" />
    <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**P.S.** Хоть данный ответ и решает вашу проблему, то что вы хотите сделать, делается в ангуляре совсем не так. Что бы показать блок, не надо запрашивать `html` у сервера. Данный `html` должен загружаться по роутингу как компонент или уже быть на странице.

Comment: Спасибо помог. Ооочень полезная инфа  С: